# Insert User Views, Country, City into database and update just views if exists

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to make a code where i can record who have visited my site and how many times in a DB table.

Here i have four columns in my 'views' table:

- ip
- city
- country
- city

Now the goes as, new user visits my site, it gets the IP-Address, city, county of the situation and checks whether it exists in table, if ip address already exists, just views will be updated as '+1'.

If ip address doesn't exists, it inserts all the data as new row into the table.

But although it is getting the IPaddress, city, country values, it isn't performing the insert query.

My code goes as:

```
<?php
/*Get user ip address*/
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

/*Get user ip address details with geoplugin.net*/
$geopluginURL='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;
$addrDetailsArr = unserialize(file_get_contents($geopluginURL));

/*Get City name by return array*/
$city = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_city'];

/*Get Country name by return array*/
$country = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_countryName'];

/*Comment out these line to see all the posible details*/
/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($addrDetailsArr);
die();*/

if(!$city){
   $city='Not Define';
}if(!$country){
   $country='Not Define';
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'dbname');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ip FROM views WHERE ip = '$ip_address'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $num = '1';

     $sql = "INSERT INTO views (ip, country, city, views)
VALUES ('$ip_address', '$country', '$city', '$num')";

} else {

    $Query = "UPDATE views SET views = views + 1 WHERE ip = '$ip_address' ";
    $RunQuery = mysqli_query ($conn, $Query);
}
?>
```

Please note that the username, pass, and dbname will be replaced with the values.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: you never execute the first query to insert ( `$sql = "INSERT INTO views ...` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to actually execute the `insert` statement and there was a mismatch in database connection object names - initially `$mysqli` and then `$conn`

```
<?php

    /*Get user ip address*/
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    /*Get user ip address details with geoplugin.net*/
    $url='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;
    $details = unserialize( file_get_contents( $url ) );

    /*Get City name by return array*/
    $city = $details['geoplugin_city'];

    /*Get Country name by return array*/
    $country = $details['geoplugin_countryName'];




    if( !$city ) $city='Not Defined';
    if( !$country ) $country='Not Defined';


    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'dbname');

    $result = $db->query( "select `ip` from `views` where `ip` = '$ip_address'" );

    if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {

        $num = 1;
        $sql = "insert into views ( `ip`, `country`, `city`, `views` ) values ( '$ip_address', '$country', '$city', $num )";
        $result = $db->query( $sql );

    } else {

        $sql = "update `views` set `views` = `views` + 1 where `ip` = '$ip_address' ";
        $result = $db->query( $sql );
    }
?>
```

---

```
$ip_address='72.16.92.178';/* hard-coded ip for testing */

#$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$url='http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='.$ip_address;

$details = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

$city = $details->geoplugin_city;
$country = $details->geoplugin_countryName;

if( !$city ) $city='Not Defined';
if( !$country ) $country='Not Defined';




$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';
$db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );




$result = $db->query( "select `ip` from `views` where `ip` = '$ip_address'" );

if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {

    $num = 1;
    $sql = "insert into views ( `ip`, `country`, `city`, `views` ) values ( '$ip_address', '$country', '$city', $num )";
    $result = $db->query( $sql );

} else {

    $sql = "update `views` set `views` = `views` + 1 where `ip` = '$ip_address' ";
    $result = $db->query( $sql );
}


printf( "OK - %s Record Added: %d", $ip_address, $result );



mysql> describe views;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip      | varchar(64)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city    | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| views   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> select * from views;
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| id | ip           | city        | country       | views |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------+
|  1 | 88.56.42.78  | Not Defined | Italy         |     5 |
|  2 | 72.16.92.178 | Centerville | United States |     2 |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: I Tried your code , it doesn't work.. in other hand, i hava database connection file where the $conn is defined..

Comment: Are there errors in the php error log in relation to this?

Comment: I have just created a test table and run the above code ( with my db connection object) and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just set the query on `$sql`  but didn't use it.

**put**

```
$RunQuery = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
```

**after**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO views (ip, country, city, views)
VALUES ('$ip_address', '$country', '$city', '$num')";
```

Comment: try to use this :  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}